# Issues with UITableViewController with Segues, Core Data and Swift

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift, xcode6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Xcode 6.0.1, Swift iOS 8

I have what I think is a pretty trvial setup, but I am missing something that is causing issues, or is the default behaviour.

I have the following:

Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller -Seque-> Table View Controller

[image]

I have the UIBarButtonItem 'Add' button (addPlayerInformationDetail) wired to the 2nd Table View Controller.  The problem is when I push the controller via the segue, code runs on the wrong Table View Controller, and it crashes.  I understand why it is crashing, but I don't understand why it's doing something on the 1st view controller. The 1st Table View Controller is also the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.

The first Table View Controller (PlayerInformationTableViewController ) is using the standard Table View Controller boiler code.  Here is the Segue calling the

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
    if debug==1 {
        println("Running: ", reflect(self).summary.pathExtension,__FUNCTION__)
    }

    if segue.identifier == "addPlayerInformationDetail" {

       //Nothing to do at the moment

    } else if segue.identifier == "editPlayerInformationDetail" {

        var indexPath:NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var vc                    = segue.destinationViewController as PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController
        vc.managedObjectID        = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath).objectID
    }
}
```

Here is the trace of all the methods and I pointed out where the code is going back to the 1st Table View Controller:

```
(Running: , AppDelegate, managedObjectContext)
(Running: , AppDelegate, persistentStoreCoordinator)
(Running: , AppDelegate, managedObjectModel)
(Running: , AppDelegate, applicationDocumentsDirectory)
(Running: , AppDelegate, application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, viewDidLoad())
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, viewWillAppear)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, numberOfSectionsInTableView)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, numberOfSectionsInTableView)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
(Running: , AppDelegate, applicationDidBecomeActive)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, prepareForSegue(_:sender:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, putABorderAroundButtons())
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, viewWillAppear)
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, refreshInterface())
newPlayer (Function)
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, newPlayer())
(Ending: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, newPlayer())

Why is it going back to PlayerInformationTableViewController???

(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, numberOfSectionsInTableView)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)


(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, numberOfSectionsInTableView)
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, numberOfSectionsInTableView)
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, tableView(_:canEditRowAtIndexPath:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, configureCell(_:atIndexPath:))
(Running: , PlayerInformationTableViewController, fetchedResultsController)
```

After the Add button is tapped and  (Ending: , PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController, newPlayer()) completes why is code in the PlayerInformationTableViewController running?  I am adding a row into Core Data, but it shouldn't have anything to do with the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in PlayerInformationTableViewController.

Here is the flow of Code in PlayerInformationDetailTableViewController

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    if debug==1 {
        println("Running: ", reflect(self).summary.pathExtension,__FUNCTION__)
    }

    refreshInterface()
}

func refreshInterface(){
    if debug==1 {
        println("Running: ", reflect(self).summary.pathExtension,__FUNCTION__)
    }

    if managedObjectID != nil {

        println("existingPlayer \(existingPlayer)")
        existingPlayer()
    } else {

        println("newPlayer \(newPlayer)")
        newPlayer()
    }
}

func newPlayer(){
    if debug==1 {
        println("Running: ", reflect(self).summary.pathExtension,__FUNCTION__)
    }

    //insert a new object in Core Data

    var newPlayerInformation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("PlayerInformation", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as PlayerInformation

    var newFirstName  = playerInformationFirstNameTextField.text
    var newLastName   = playerInformationLastNameTextField.text
    var newBirthPlace = playerInformationBirthPlaceTextField.text

    newPlayerInformation.firstName  = playerInformationFirstNameTextField.text
    newPlayerInformation.lastName   = playerInformationLastNameTextField.text
    newPlayerInformation.birthPlace = playerInformationBirthPlaceTextField.text

    if debug==1 {
        println("Ending: ", reflect(self).summary.pathExtension,__FUNCTION__)
    }
}
```

I hope I explained this properlly, as it's been really frustrating and I'm sure it's something simple I've missed.  If I coment out // newPlayer() in func refreshInterface(), the code nevers goes back to PlayerInformationTableViewController. Thanks in advance. -PaulS.

Answer (score 1):

The tracelog shows that your NSFetchedResultsController is detecting a change in its managedObjectContext, due to adding a new record. It immediately updates the related information `numberOfRowsInSection`...

According to the [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW23)

> In addition, fetched results controllers provide the following features:
>
> ```
> Optionally monitor changes to objects in the associated managed object context, and report changes in the results set to its delegate (see The Controller’s Delegate).
> ```

To disable this tracking the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate should be set to `nil`

Comment: When/where should I set the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate to `nil`, in my segue?

Comment: The `NSFetchedResultsController` notifies your `PlayerInformationTableViewController` that the table data has to be updated. This is a logical behaviour. You have to check why your code crashes.

Comment: While this isn't the answer, it has pointed me in the right direction to find some logic errors in my code.  My problem was I was inserting a new record into my database, before entering data, thus my data was always nil.  Problem solved.  Thanks